# firebase deploy showing blank index file with no app displayed

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular, angularfire

I am trying to deploy a clone of https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase. I haven't changed anything yet (except for pointing to my own firebase), and I'm just trying to get it to deploy. I am able to run the app locally using gulp, but when I deploy to firebase, I just see an empty white page. The index page is loading, but the app isn't running: https://minneapolis.firebaseapp.com/

My src file looks like this:

[image]

My firebase.json file looks just like the [firebase example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) with the change of "app" to "src" which is the name of my directory:

```
{
  "firebase": "MY-APP-NAME-HERE",
  "public": "src",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Whne I run locally, I get a console message that says:

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

But I am importing {enableProdMode} so I think it should be working?

The only console error I'm getting is one that I can't understand:

```
GET https://use.typekit.net/c/7019ef/1w;aktiv-grotesk-std,2,gd9:W:n3,gdC:W:n4/l…1128a5fe934af4ba55e6671197dcad3444af3a2796420a2ac4ee887f75bbe33a3b6e13af3f
```

Is that what is causing my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build locally the gulp command is injecting a script into the index.html.

```
<script src="/common.js?4743575164d30a9c3044"></script><script src="/vendor.js?4743575164d30a9c3044"></script><script src="/main.js?4743575164d30a9c3044"></script>
```

You should run

```
bash scripts/dist.sh
```

Then deploy the `target` folder to firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I'm away from my computer right now, buy I'll try this when I get back! I think this is right brigade target is what was originally in the config file.

Comment: It worked! For some reason, I had to delete my node_modules folder and then rerun install npm, but it worked! Thank you!